# Formatting in quantikz circuit diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, circuits

[image]

How do I club these wires under the class named 'MY TERM', do I use `gateinput`.

This is the code:

```
\begin{quantikz}[row sep={0.7cm,between origins}]
\lstick{\ket{\tilde{C}^0_{ijk}}} &\qw &\qw &\qw & \qw&\qw & \qw&\qw \gateinput[4]{$My term$}\\ 
\lstick{\ket{\tilde{C}^1_{ijk}}} &\qw &\qw &\qw & \qw&\qw & \qw&\qw\\ 
\lstick{$\vdots$} &\qw &\qw &\qw & \qw&\qw & \qw&\qw\\                              \lstick{\ket{\tilde{C}^{q-1}_{ijk}}} &\qw &\qw &\qw & \qw&\qw & \qw&\qw\\  
\end{quantikz}
```

The result is:

[image]

But this is not correct, I want a big brace on the extreme left before the `lstick`

Comment: Could you please add a sketch showing what you want? It seems that you don't need to use `tikz` or `circuitikz` here

Comment: I want the big braces on the extreme left to denote that these 4 items belong to the same class

Comment: What I mean is what you want to get not what you are already having. Moreover please make your code compilable

Comment: I think that there is a tag confusion here, `circuitikz` and `quantikz` are (very) different packages...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?
[image]

I had to fudge the spacing of the vdots slightly, but here's how I did it:

```
\begin{quantikz}
\lstick[4]{My term} & \ket{\tilde{C}^0_{ijk}} &\qw &\qw &\qw & \qw&\qw & \qw&\qw\\ 
&\ket{\tilde{C}^1_{ijk}} &\qw &\qw &\qw & \qw&\qw & \qw&\qw\\ 
&\phantom{Ca}\vdots\phantom{Ci} &\qw &\qw &\qw & \qw&\qw & \qw&\qw\\
&\ket{\tilde{C}^{q-1}_{ijk}} &\qw &\qw &\qw & \qw&\qw & \qw&\qw  
\end{quantikz}
```

Comment: yes thanx that is what i wanted to do

Answer (score 4):

You can always locally change some pgfkeys to make these libraries do whatever you like them to do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
\begin{document}
\bgroup
\tikzset{every right delimiter/.style={yshift=2.5ex}}
\tikzcdset{every matrix/.append style={right delimiter=\}}}
\begin{quantikz}[row sep={0.7cm,between origins}]
\lstick{\ket{\tilde{C}^0_{ijk}}} &\qw &\qw &\qw & \qw&\qw & \qw&\qw %\gateinput[4]{$My term$}
\\ 
\lstick{\ket{\tilde{C}^1_{ijk}}} &\qw &\qw &\qw & \qw&\qw & \qw&\qw\\ 
\lstick{$\vdots$} &\qw &\qw &\qw & \qw&\qw & \qw&\qw\\                              
\lstick{\ket{\tilde{C}^{q-1}_{ijk}}} &\qw &\qw &\qw & \qw&\qw & \qw&\qw\\  
\end{quantikz} 
\egroup\raisebox{1.5ex}{My term}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A perhaps even simpler option is to use the good old `\}` for that. The only thing you need to notice is that you need `ampersand replacement` because ... (censored) ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
\begin{document}
$\left.\text{\tikzcdset{every matrix/.append style={ampersand replacement=\&}}
\begin{quantikz}[row sep={0.7cm,between origins}]
\lstick{\ket{\tilde{C}^0_{ijk}}} \&\qw \&\qw \&\qw \& \qw\&\qw \& \qw\&\qw \\ 
\lstick{\ket{\tilde{C}^1_{ijk}}} \&\qw \&\qw \&\qw \& \qw\&\qw \& \qw\&\qw\\ 
\lstick{$\vdots$} \&\qw \&\qw \&\qw \& \qw\&\qw \& \qw\&\qw\\                              
\lstick{\ket{\tilde{C}^{q-1}_{ijk}}} \&\qw \&\qw \&\qw \& \qw\&\qw \& \qw\&\qw\\  
\end{quantikz}}\right\}$ My term
\end{document}
```

[image]