# Latex file working on Tex studio but not on WinEdt

Tags: tikz-pgf, texstudio, winedt

I have this latex with with quantikz package

```
\documentclass{article}

             \usepackage{bm}

             \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
                          \usepackage{tabularx}
                            \usepackage{multirow}
                            \usepackage{booktabs}
                             \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \usepackage{algpseudocode}
    \usepackage{algorithm}
     \usepackage{breqn}
      \usepackage{lipsum}
     \usepackage{subfig}
     \usepackage{tikz} 
       \usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
     \begin{document}
                   \begin{figure}[!ht]
            \centering
            \begin{quantikz}[column sep=0.095cm]
                \lstick{$\ket{c_0}$}  &  \gate[3]{\textsc{MAJ}}  &\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\gate[3]{\textsc{UMA}}\\
                \lstick{$\ket{b_0}$}  & \qw &\qw                             &\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\\
                \lstick{$\ket{a_0}$}  &\qw  & \gate[3]{\textsc{MAJ}}      &\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\gate[3]{\textsc{UMA}}&\\
                \lstick{$\ket{b_1}$}  &  \qw&\qw                             &\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw& \qw       &  \qw       & \\
                \lstick{$\ket{a_1}$}  &  & &\gate[3]{\textsc{MAJ}}     &\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\gate[3]{\textsc{UMA}}& \qw       &  \qw       & \\
                \lstick{$\ket{b_2}$}  & \qw &\qw &\qw                           &\qw &\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw&\qw& \qw       &  \qw       &  \qw       & \\
                \lstick{$\ket{a_2}$}  & \qw &\qw &\qw &\gate[3]{\textsc{MAJ}}   &\qw &\qw &\qw &\qw &\gate[3]{\textsc{UMA}}& \qw       &  \qw       &  \qw       & \\
                \lstick{$\ket{b_3}$}  & \qw &\qw &\qw &                \qw         & \qw& \qw&\qw &\qw & \qw       &  \qw       &  \qw       &  \qw       &  \\
                \lstick{$\ket{a_3}$}  & \qw &\qw &\qw &\qw & \gate[3]{\textsc{MAJ}}&\qw &\qw &\gate[3]{\textsc{UMA}} & \qw       &  \qw       &  \qw       &  \qw       &  \\
                \lstick{$\ket{b_4}$}  &\qw  &\qw &\qw &\qw & \qw                      &\qw &\qw & \qw       &  \qw       &  \qw       &  \qw       &  \qw       & \\
                \lstick{$\ket{a_4}$}  & \qw &\qw &\qw &\qw &\qw & \gate[3]{\textsc{MAJ}} &\gate[3]{\textsc{UMA}}& \qw       &  \qw       &  \qw       &  \qw       &  \qw       & \\
                \lstick{$\ket{b_5}$}  & \qw &\qw &\qw &\qw &\qw &\qw                        &   \qw       &  \qw       &  \qw       &  \qw       &  \qw       &  \qw       & \\
                \lstick{$\ket{a_5}$}  & \qw & \qw& \qw& \qw& \qw&                 \qw       &  \qw       &  \qw       &  \qw       &  \qw       &  \qw       &  \qw       &
            \end{quantikz}
            \caption{ Reversible Ripple carry adder for $n=6$}
            \label{Ripple}
         \end{figure} 



     \end{document}
```

It is compiling correctly in Tex studio, but giving an unusual error in WinEdt
The error is :
Missing number, treated as zero.
 
                   \pgf@matrix@column@sep@14 
l.108                        \end{quantikz}

Can somebody help  it is related with the answer to : [Formatting in quantikz circuit diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490031/formatting-in-quantikz-circuit-diagram/490607#490607)

Comment: This code can compile nowhere – it is lacking  (at least) `\documentclass`.

Comment: i forgot to paste it here, now i have done that

Comment: Neither texstudio nor winedt compile anything on their own; they are just front-ends for a TeX distribution. Which TeX distribution do you employ?  If both front-ends interact with the same TeX distribution, and if you can compile your LaTeX document when using one front-end but not when using the other, it suggests that the front-end that's giving you trouble wasn't installed correctly.

Comment: i am using mik tex

Comment: you presumably have two miktex installations or user and admin versions of the same and have updated one and not the other. any differences are unrelated to which editor you use, texstudio or winedt or notepad make no difference. compare the log files of the two runs and any file versions reported, and update both text distributions.

Comment: I agree on the same MiKTeX base running WinEdt is **correctly not compiling** due to the high number of errors 34+warnings whereas I can force a compilation in TeXstudio Wonder which one is right result ?